# Should this PostgreSQL query use the indexes?

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE soils (
    sample_id       TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    project_id      TEXT, 
    technician_id   TEXT
);
CREATE INDEX soils_idx
ON soils
USING btree
(sample_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE TABLE assays (
    sample_id   TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
    mo_ppm      NUMERIC
    );
CREATE INDEX assays_idx
ON assays
USING btree
(sample_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Each table contains about a half million records, and, in reality, about 20 additional columns each, of type TEXT (omitted in the DDL posted above to save time here).

When I perform the query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT
   s.sample_id, s.project_id, s.technician_id, a.mo_ppm
FROM
   soils AS s INNER JOIN assays AS a ON s.sample_id = a.sample_id
```

I get 2 SEQ SCANs, rather than a lookup to the index.  Is that expected behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have no `WHERE` conditions, you effectively read the whole table. It's cheaper to run sequential scans and not involve any indexes at all.

Try:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT s.sample_id, s.project_id, s.technician_id, a.mo_ppm
FROM   soils s
JOIN   assays a USING (sample_id)
WHERE  <some condition that returns few rows>;
```

... and an index matching the `WHERE` condition should be used.

You don't need to define an index on a `PRIMARY KEY` column. A PK constraint is implemented with a unique index automatically. Your additional index is redundant and of no use.

An index on a foreign key column would be a good idea, but there isn't one in your example, which looks odd. Like the two tables could be combined into one. Probably just over-simplification for the test case.

Finally, for big tables, I would consider using a simple `integer` primary key instead of `text`, possibly a [`serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column. That's typically faster.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's expected behaviour. On the other hand it depends on your `random_page_cost`, `seq_page_cost` and `effective_cache_size` settings. Your query doesn't have `WHERE` clause hence it might be faster to read everything sequentially. You can try to penalise sequential scan:

```
set enable_seqscan = off;
explain analyse <your query>;
```

and then compare plan/cost/IO wait (it is not possible to disable seq-scan but it gets very high cost -- ~1e7 (or 1e8)).

If you have SSD and `WHERE` clause in your query then you can lower [random_page_cost to 1.5..2.5](http://www.databasesoup.com/2012/05/random-page-cost-revisited.html) and encourage PG to use index.